# Position an invisible div element over a photo(onclick)(repl.it)

Tags: javascript, html, css

[Visual of element placement](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FthXz.jpg)

I am trying to make a little “pet the dog game” and I would like to put a div over his head and when you click the DIV it will trigger a JS function to change the photo to a .gif then back again here is my code
JS:

```js
 function pet_head(){
    var image = getElementById("image");
    image.src="DogPet.gif";
    setTimeout(function(){
      image.src="dog.jpeg";

    }, 1000//length of gif
   );

};
```

HTML:

```html
<div class="main">
  <img id="image" src="dog.jpeg">
  <div class="click></div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```css
img{
height:100%;
width100%;
position:absolute;
}
```

Comment: What's your issue?

Comment: My DIV is not getting placed over the IMG. It is being placed underneath. I have tried `z-index`

Comment: It seems to be fine, you just have some typos

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use absolute in the image it will always be on top of everything else.

Take a look below and see if that is what you looking for.

```js
function pet_head(event) {
  /*var image = getElementById("image");
  image.src = "DogPet.gif";
  setTimeout(function() {
      image.src = "dog.jpeg";
  }, 1000 //length of gif
  );*/
  
  
  alert('changed');
};

document.getElementById('click').addEventListener('click', pet_head);
```

```css
img {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

div {
  /* This will center the image horizontally */
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  position: absolute;
}

div#click {
  color: green;
  border: 2px solid red;
  top: 14%;
  height: 45%;
  width: 300px;
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
  <div id="click"></div>
  <img id="image" src="https://i.insider.com/5df126b679d7570ad2044f3e?width=1100&format=jpeg&auto=webp" />
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a working version of your code. Also note that (besides removing code typos) I added `object-fit: cover` to your `img`, so that it preserves aspect ratio as the viewport size changes.

```js
function pet_head() {
   // var image = document.getElementById("image");
   alert("petting the dog");
   /* image.src = "DogPet.gif";
   setTimeout(function() {
       image.src = "dog.jpeg";
   
     }, 1000 //length of gif
   ); */

 };
 
 document.querySelector(".click").addEventListener("click", pet_head);
```

```css
img {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  object-fit: cover;  
}

.click {
  position: absolute;
  left: 49%;
  top: 22px;
  height: 13vh;
  width: 17vw;
  cursor: pointer;
}

/* Presentational styles */

.click {
  background: yellow;
  opacity: .1;
}

html, body {
  margin: 0;
}

*, *::before, &::after { 
  box-sizing: border-box; 
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
  <img id="image" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/FthXz.jpg">
  <div class="click"></div>
</div>
```

[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/4vh1te79/3/)